# Recolouring PDFs

Tags: pdf

Is it possible, with DocView or pdf-tools or something else, to recolour pdfs (e.g. by inverting or choosing a particular colour for background and foreground)?  It's a bit annoying when using a dark colour theme to have to view pdfs with white backgrounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a dark ("midnight") theme with `pdf-tools`.

Right-click somewhere within the displayed pdf, go to "Render Options" in the menu (about half-way down) and select "Midnight mode".

Alternatively, do `M-x pdf-view-midnight-minor-mode RET`.

The colours used by the "midnight mode" are specified by the variable `pdf-view-midnight-colors` (see the docstring with `C-h v pdf-view-midnight-colors RET` — in brief the format of the variable is `(FOREGROUND . BACKGROUND)`).

You may also need to adjust the colour of the margins, mode-line and other elements of Emacs's UI.